# Filtering a raster by pixel value ? (Qgis)

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, filter

I have downloaded Globcover data in GeoTIFF format. I want to create a new grid which only has values where the Globcover data (the only band in the TIF file) has one certain value (`==190`).

Can I do this with GDAL?

If not, which way should I go? The procedure should be callable from a Shell script (Linux). I have QGIS installed (but no clue how to use it).

Comment: The question is Gdal specific, the answer is Qgis specific. Then, could we rename the question ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In QGIS you have the raster calculator (Under the "Raster" menu) which will do what you want. (not a shell script command)

- Load your Globcover raster into QGIS, and open the Raster Calculator.
- The raster will appear in the "Bands" window.
- Enter a name for the new "Output Layer".
- Now double click on the Globcover band name so that it appears in the lower "Raster calculator expression".
- Then complete the expression by typing "=190" in that window.
- Click OK to create the new raster.

Note that you will have a raster with values of either 190 or 0 everywhere else. You can further use gdal_translate to set the zeros to NULL.

HTH,
Micha