# From Raster to Masked and Filtered Polygon Vector

Tags: raster, vector, clip, polygonize

I have a set of rasters (geologic risk) from which I want to extract zones with a specific color, clipping them with a polygon (administrative borders), outputting a shapefile.
I'm using QGis (and GDAL from command line).
I know I can use clipper, polygonize and show only features with the value I need, but:

1. it takes ages to polygonize the raster, and I don't want much of the information in it;
2. clipper doesn't work because the polygon border is larger than each raster, but fits inside the sum of all rasters
3. to make things complicated, the zone I would like to extract don't have the same color value in all rasters (but do have the same rgb color)

How can I solve it in a fast way?

Comment: I think I got my answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27359/filtering-a-raster-by-pixel-value-with-gdal  

I simply have to rasterize my polygon (I addedd a field with value=1), then use raster calculator to do:

    mask * map = color value

then I can use polygonyze (and do a join)

Comment: it is a different enough question that you should accomplish the outcome and then post as an answer below and check the answer as correct. that is how we roll here at GSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got my answer: [Filtering a raster by pixel value ? (Qgis)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27359/filtering-a-raster-by-pixel-value-with-gdal)

I simply have to rasterize my polygon (I addedd a field with value=1), then use raster calculator to do:

```
mask * map = color value
```

then I can use polygonyze (and join)