# How to conditionnally assign a new value to pixels of a raster image?

Tags: raster, gdal, ogr, elevation, topography

**Given a topographic GIS raster** of one country `crop.tif`:

**Given a know pixel value** such as elevation (z) is +73 :

```
$ gdallocationinfo crop.tif 1 1 -valonly
> 73
```

**Given an elevation threshold** n = 50 (meters)

**How to set the value of all/this pixels where z >= n to 50 ?**

The solution should be with gdal or in console.

---

Related to : [Gdal: How to get a pixel's value from raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69066/), [gdal_polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html).

---

**EDIT:** I eventually used the formula `--calc="50*(A>50)" --NoDataValue=0` standing for `"new calc where value set as 50 when value in input A > 50, else value set as 0"`

> gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="50*(A>50)" --NoDataValue=0

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best all round tool here is a raster calculator.

gdal_calc is a GDAL raster calculator implemented in Python [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py), with some examples [here](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/gdal_calc-py-raster-calculator-using-numby-functions/).

If you e.g. wants to keep values above +50:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A>50)" --NoDataValue=0
```

You can specify several files -A to -Z, where each of them get a corresponding variable in the expression.

In this case, the boolean expression (A>50) returns either 1 or 0, and is then multiplied with A. The result is then stored in the corresponding pixel in outputfile.

Not sure if you need a programmatic approach or a manual one, but QGis has a raster calculator. See related question with answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27359/filtering-a-raster-by-pixel-value-qgis).

Comment: +1 untill test for validation. I was looking for a programmatic approach, but others may be interested by the manual one. :)

Comment: Note: I need to polygonize afterward. So I need to set values >= 50 to 50 (one same value).

Comment: Ok ! new calc is equal to 50 when -A>50 : `gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="50*(A>50)" --NoDataValue=0` . Please **add** this operation and explanation to your answer so I validate it !

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes. Note that 50*(A>50) results in either 50 or 0.

Comment: Maybe a silly addition, but when inserting the calc expression with these conditionals, remember to wrap the "" in outer '' quotes. This is necessary here where if the expression was just A*50 it doesn't want the double quotes.