# gdal_calc.py outputs huge files

Tags: raster, gdal

I think this is a general enough question to apply to more than just gdal_calc, but perhaps not.  When I run

```
gdal_calc.py -A map.tif --outfile=deforestation_00-10.tif --NoDataValue=0 --calc="A >= 7"
```

on a 38000 x 38000 62.5MB tif, the output is 1.37GB (and still 38000 x 38000).  I feel like i'm probably missing something big here, i.e. how tif data is stored.  [the same thing happens when I run it using the raster calculator in qGIS]  Thanks in advance.

Bonus points--anyone know how to include and/or logic in the --calc="..." in order to evaluate the following: (map@1 >= 7 AND map@1 <= 9) OR ((map@1 >= 10 AND map@1 <= 12) * 2)

Comment: Are you aware that TIFF actually comprises [multiple formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format), including (but not requiring) compression? Because 38000 * 38000 / 2^30 = 1.35, it is clear the output is not compressed and the input is compressed. For an example of using Boolean operations in `gdal_calc`, please see [this recent answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/how-to-conditionnally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image/69133#69133).

Comment: Your "bonus points" line should probably have been asked as a separate question - that helps keep things organized and easy to search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `--co=creationoptions` parameter to compress the output.

```
gdal_calc.py --co="COMPRESS=LZW" -A map.tif --outfile=deforestation_00-10.tif --NoDataValue=0 --calc="A >= 7"
```

For more compression options, see the GDAL [GTiff format description](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html).

Answer (score 9):

## Filesize question

If the result data is boolean True/False (or 1s and 0s), use `--type=Byte` with the creation option `NBITS=1` to create a file with 1 bit per sample. This will pack the uncompressed data 8 times smaller. And then as @Luke has answered, specify a compression to use. There are a dozen different compression methods; another good one is `COMPRESS=DEFLATE`.

```
gdal_calc -A map.tif --outfile=out.tif --type=Byte --co="NBITS=1" --co="COMPRESS=DEFLATE" --calc="A >= 7"
```

With some example data that I have, I'm seeing a compression ratio of 0.15%. So I'd expect a result from a 1.37GB file to compress down to about 2MB.

## Bonus question

According to the help for `--calc`:

> calculation in gdalnumeric syntax using `+-/*` or any numpy array functions (i.e. [`logical_and()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html))

The expression is processed by [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval). So try this:

```
--calc="logical_or(logical_and(A >= 7, A <= 9), logical_and(A >= 10, A <= 12))"
```

I wasn't sure what the whole `* 2` part of your original expression was, so it is left out.

Comment: Hmm, was trying to get output such that values 7 <= A <= 9 would evaluate to 1, and values 10 <= A <= 12 would evaluate to 2, using a raster mask as described [here](http://spatialgalaxy.net/2012/01/25/using-the-qgis-raster-calculator/).  However, although `logical_and(A >= 10, A <= 12) * 2` evaluates to 2 for inputs 10, 11, 12, adding it as the second input to the `logical_or` function results in all inputs 7 <= A <= 12 returning 1 (I guess b/c when 'logical_or` evaluates 2, it reads it as `True`, which returns 1).

Comment: Update: apparently logicals here are not evaluated the same as logicals elsewhere.  E.g. in python, `False or 2` returns 2 while here it returns 1.  I can get the result I need by running `gdal_calc` three times--one to produce the value 1 for 7,8,9; a second time to produce the value 2 for 10,11,12; and third time to combine them--but wondering if there's a better way.