# Can I edit pixels values of an image with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, data, image

There is a method with GDAL (used in C/C++) to edit pixel values of a georeferenced image, maintaining the original file? Or I have to create a new dataset? My goal is to maintain ALL originals metadata, so I think the creation of a new dataset is drawback.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit pixel values using **[gdal_calc.py](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py)** creating a new dataset and maintaining all the original metadata. For instance, see this useful example: [How to conditionnally assign a new value to pixels of a raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/how-to-conditionnally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image?rq=1)
Alternatively you can write your own Python scripts to do more complex calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't write that I use GDAL in C/C++. Sorry.

Comment: So you can start from the [GDAL API Tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html).