# How to pass value of a band to and other band and change its value?

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, hillshade, bash

Using `gdaldem hillshade`, I get a one-band hillshade ([download here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Shadedrelief.tmp.tif), 2MB) :

```
 gdaldem hillshade crop_xl.tmp.tif Shadedrelief.tmp.tif -s 111120 -z 5 -az 315 -alt 60 -compute_edges
```

I currently can duplicate its band 1 (grey scale) into the band 2 (alpha) via :

```
 gdal_translate -b 1 -b 1 -co COMPRESS=LZW  -co ALPHA=YES ./Shadedrelief.tmp.tif ./Shadedrelief.2bands.tmp.tif
```

But what I want to do is to get the **inverted value of band 1** into band 2. The equation is :

```
 y = -x + 255;  // where x is -b 1 's value, and y is -b 2 's value.
```

Given a tif hillshade as provided, **how to get the inverted value of band 1 into band 2 ?**

---

See also : [How to conditionnally assign a new value to pixels of a raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/) , [gdal_calc : fails with value 0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144707/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`gdal_calc.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) to invert the band :

```
gdal_calc.py -A Shadedrelief.tif --outfile=InvertedShadedrelief.tif --calc="255-A"
```

[gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) helps to merge 2 files into a two band image (or a 2 band vrt), it takes the first band of each input into band 1 and band 2:

```
gdalbuildvrt -separate final.vrt Shadedrelief.tif InvertedShadedrelief.tif
```

[gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) helps to convert to tif and compress the file:

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co ALPHA=YES ./final.vrt ./final.tif
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I understand command 1, but It's my first contact with [vrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) and I don't understand the 2nd command.  What are its input and output ? I would expect a kind of merge of `input.tif -b 1` + `result.tif -b 1` into a two bands `final.tif -b 1 -b 2`.

Comment: vrt is virtual raster file: you can manipulate it in most software as if it was a real 2 band image, but it is only a small xml file. Basically, if you want a single tif file, you can do : gdal_translate final.vrt final.tif

Comment: Tested, working, and happily validated !