# Binarise Raster within range with gdal_calc.py

Tags: qgis, gdal, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I am looking to utilise **gdal_calc** to batch binarise a few hundred rasters.
I am having dificulty though in relation to the correct formula to achieve this.
I am trying to make all the values between **-20 and -15** in a raster **= 1** and everything **else = 0**, making 0 NoData.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionnally assign a new value to pixels of a raster image?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/how-to-conditionnally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **gdal_calc.py** with [conditional statements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/how-to-conditionnally-assign-a-new-value-to-pixels-of-a-raster-image).
This should do the trick:

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="(A>=-20)*(A<=-15)" --NoDataValue=0
```

or

```
gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="logical_and(A>=-20,A<=-15)" --NoDataValue=0
```

This returns values 0 and 1. Add "255*" if you want values 0 and 255.