# Setting conditions in QGIS

Tags: qgis

How do I set conditions in QGIS (ie. temperature map, show only areas that meet certain condition (avg temp 9-21 celsius) ?

basically, I want my map to show only areas that meet the condition (certain temperature, certain hours of sunlight per years...) stuff like that. Would also be cool if I could overlap those.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to **filter your layer** using a formula based on one (or ++) attribute of your table.
Go to **layer properties/General/Provider feature filter** and build your query using the *query builder* button.

If your have overlapping conditions u should rather try a rule based rendering of your layer.
Go to **layer properties/style/choose rule-based** and build the differents rendering rules of your layer.

Comment: I don't have those settings, I downloaded this map
http://worldclim.org/version2
The avg temperature one in highest resolution
will raster calculator do the trick?
one more edit>
nope, don't know how to use the raster calculator, in the color gradient I can change the values, is that the temperature?

Comment: i think u're talking about **raster** layers which are 'images' my answers were refferring to **vector** layers (which are point, line or polygon geometries) ...

Comment: Yup, I understand that. You're right, I am using raster images. Check this:
https://imgur.com/a/XGXpn6m
Does this mean that all I have to do is enter the style settings, set the color gradient minimum and maximum to what I want, and that's it?

Comment: i'm not so used to raster data but check this link which should be the answer to your question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27359/filtering-a-raster-by-pixel-value-qgis

Comment: Greatly appreciated sir, I'll see what I can do

Comment: Hi @DanIonis and snaileater. In the `Layer Properties | Transparency` tab, there is `Custom transparency options` where you can add transparent zones by clicking green plus icon. Try adding `From=0` and `To=9`.